# Is there anyway to programatically delete a task from the task scheduler aside from using its name in C#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, taskservice

This is what I'm currently using, but I'm looking for another way that doesn't require the task name.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask(TaskName);
}
```

Comment: Then how do you plan to identify it?

Comment: @CallumLinington : Maybe via reflection?

Comment: @CallumLinington I believe you are referring to the wrong type of Task. The Op is concerned with Windows Task Scheduler, not `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` as referred to by your reference source